# Webkit CSS Transitioning Rotation Not Spinning

Tags: css, webkit

I'm having difficulty rotating an item a full 360 degrees in webkit using CSS transitions.

I've created a JS Fiddle to show what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/PnTk8/2/

The transition should happen in 2 steps. First, the item should just rotate along the Y axis for a 1/2 turn. Then, once that transition is complete, it should rotate the opposite direction a full turn and scale down to 1/2 the original size. The problem I'm having is that the second transition is only scaling and not rotating, even though rotate values of `rotateY(-360deg)` and `rotateY(0deg)` should cause a full rotation.

This is just a proof-of-concept, so I'm only targeting webkit at the moment. However, I'd like to stick with transitions, and not keyframe animations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my knowledge, rotate from rotateY(-180deg) to rotateY(-360deg) would be as the same state as rotateY(0). Let's put it this way: imagine you flip a piece of paper twice in the same direction, would be totally the same state as the very beginning. As a result, the browser take it for 'no changes at all', therefore no transition upon the rotation.

another example would make this even clearer:

given deg. set to your case, rotateY(-90deg) => rotateY(-300deg) => rotateY(60deg) would work just the same, the second transition won't start. Becuz relative to the original state: rotateY(0), rotateY(-300deg) is just at the same state as rotateY(60deg).

Comment: While the view may be the same, there is a difference between a 0 deg rotation and a -360 deg rotation. I put together a little fiddle to show that you can transition an item between 0 to -360deg rotation: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/LXv5v/  For some reason, it just doesn't work as expected in my example, when it is the second transition being enacted.

Comment: @RussellUresti I just remade a demo to mimic your case: http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/CpdJG/, and it works perfectly as you wish. As of your original case, still trouble shooting tho.

Comment: This seems to work. I can't quite figure out what the different between this and my code is (except for things that shouldn't make a difference, like targeting the image instead of a container), but it looks like a good baseline to start from and then re-apply the positioning and markup I want to have. Thanks.